# Calculating averages in COBOL linux- errors with calculation statement

Tags: linux, cobol

I am running two errors on compile that I cannot figure out. "calcavg.cob: in paragraph 'CALC-AVG':" and "calcavg.cob:30: error: 'INTS' requires one subscript"  I cannot figure these out.  below is the code for the program

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. ASSIGNMENT4.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  NUM-OF-INTS        PIC 99.
   01  INT-ARRAY.
       05  INTS OCCURS 15 TIMES PIC 999.
   01  TOTAL              PIC 9(5)V99.
   01  AVG                PIC 9(3)V99.
   01  COUNTER            PIC 99.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-LOGIC.
       DISPLAY "Enter number of integers to average (2-15): ".
       ACCEPT NUM-OF-INTS.

       PERFORM ACCEPT-INTS
       PERFORM CALC-AVG
       DISPLAY "Average: " AVG DISPLAY "ZZZ.99".
       STOP RUN.

   ACCEPT-INTS.
       DISPLAY "Enter integers to average: ".
       PERFORM VARYING COUNTER FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL COUNTER>NUM-OF-INTS
           DISPLAY "Integer " COUNTER ": "
           ACCEPT INTS(COUNTER)
       END-PERFORM.

   CALC-AVG.
       COMPUTE TOTAL = FUNCTION SUM(INTS(1:NUM-OF-INTS))
       COMPUTE AVG = TOTAL / NUM-OF-INTS.

   EXIT.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COMPUTE TOTAL = FUNCTION SUM(INTS(1:NUM-OF-INTS))
```

`(1:NUM-OF-INTS)` is not a subscript. This format is used for reference modification; that is, to select a substring from a data-item that is `USAGE DISPLAY`. You appear to be using it as an array slice for the entire table.

Use this instead:

```
05  INTS OCCURS 2 to 15 TIMES
        DEPENDING ON NUM-OF-INTS PIC 999.

COMPUTE TOTAL = FUNCTION SUM(INTS(ALL))
```

The `DEPENDING ON` limits the number of items to be added together with the `ALL` subscript. The `ALL` subscript with `SUM` will add that many numbers together. The resulting value then be moved to `TOTAL`.

---

To get around the problem of not recognizing `ALL`. Use the following, to replace the `COMPUTE` statement:

```
05  INTS OCCURS 2 to 15 TIMES
        DEPENDING ON NUM-OF-INTS INDEXED BY INTS-IDX PIC 999.

MOVE 0 TO TOTAL
PERFORM VARYING INTS-IDX FROM 1 BY 1
UNTIL INTS-IDX > NUM-OF-INTS
    ADD INTS(INTS-IDX) TO TOTAL
END-PERFORM
```

Comment: its still returning errors, now "syntax error, unexpected ALL

Comment: I am wondering under the ACCEPT-INTS. the PERFORM, DISPLAY, and ACCEPT, should they have "." at the end? the IDE rulers that are set though make it impossible to add anything else to line 24.  should the rulers be adjusted?

Comment: @SteveX - Missed the 2 through 15 for the count. With those changes, works on my system. The `ALL` subscript was added in an amendment for COBOL 85. If it is not being recognized, it is a lower level compiler.

Comment: If its still saying unexpected ALL, is that due to the lower level compiler?

Comment: @SteveX - Statements within an inline `PERFORM` must not end with ".". Other problems I noted: The `EXIT` statement, at the last line, is not needed; `AVG` should be `PIC ZZ9.99`; `DISPLAY "ZZZ.99".` seems to have no purpose and may be removed. I cannot comment on the IDE rulers because that's not the IDE I use.

Comment: @SteveX - Work on GnuCOBOL began as OpenCOBOL over 20 years ago. I know that an IDE was released many years ago with a version of OpenCOBOL. If that is the IDE you are using, then I'd say yes, that is a low-level compiler. But I am unclear as to when various updates were made, such as support for `ALL`. If you provide the version number of the compiler, maybe someone can point to what it can and cannot accept as code.

Comment: Yes, that worked, to override the IDE of not recognizing ALL.  Thank you very much for the help!